# Jetty returns 400 for requests for absolute URL in the http request

Tags: java, http, tomcat, jetty

I've replaced the Tomcat by Jetty. Now I have 400 http error code for requests sent by a third party system. As I see, the difference with my tests sent by `curl` and a web-browser is the url in the http verb:

```
POST http://10.15.1.9:49302 HTTP/1.0
Host: 10.15.1.9
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 71065
User-Agent: hpost/0.1
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: */*
```

this request doesn't work, but post with relative URL such as `POST / HTTP/1.0` works fine. Who is wrong? I cannot change the third party system, so, is it possible to make jetty accept such requests?

I've tried Jetty v6.1.26, v7.6.4 and v8.1.4 - works the same.

---

Ok, I think the reason is missing trailing slash after the url, the `POST http://10.15.1.9:49302/ HTTP/1.0` works fine.

Does any body know if it is jetty problem or the client sends malformed url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [reported the issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1533), it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

While the HTTP spec [RFC-2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) says that the [server must accept absoluteuri's](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2) for the request line, this is generally only used for proxy requests.

To Jetty, the request line `POST http://10.15.1.9:49302 HTTP/1.0` is viewed as a HTTP/1.0 request, and fall into the rules of [RFC-1945 for Request Line URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-5.1.2) that states absoluteuri's are always Proxy requests.